# Emacs indent when press return

Tags: emacs, markdown, indentation

I had many markdowns files in my project and I need to change they everytime.

For example, in a changelog.md I has this format:

```
## 1.11.3 (2016-10-01)
- Fix bug
- New feature....
```

When I press return, the emacs add a new tab in the current line and add another tab in the new line created.
How can I deactive this indentation only for markdown files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do it by defining a function to disable `electric-indent-mode` and adding it to the `markdown-mode-hook`:

```
(defun my-disable-electric-indent ()
  "Disable electric indenting."
  (electric-indent-local-mode -1))

(add-hook 'markdown-mode-hook
          #'my-disable-electric-indent)
```